# How to get a pointer value in Haskell?

Tags: memory, pointers, haskell

I wish to manipulate data on a very low level.

Therefore I have a function that receives a virtual memory address as an integer and "does stuff" with this memory address. I interfaced this function from C, so it has the type `(CUInt -> a)`.
The memory I want to link is a `Word8` in a file. Sadly, I have no idea how to access the pointer value to that `Word8`.

To be clear, I do not need the value of the Word8, i need the value to the virtual memory address, which is the value of the pointer to it.

Comment: Can't you make a function in C to dereference the pointer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the sake of a simple example, say you want to add an offset to the pointer.

Front matter:

```
module Main where
import Control.Monad (forM_)
import Data.Char (chr)
import Data.Word (Word8)
import Foreign.ForeignPtr (ForeignPtr, withForeignPtr)
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr, plusPtr)
import Foreign.Storable (peek)
import System.IO.MMap (Mode(ReadOnly), mmapFileForeignPtr)
```

Yes, you wrote that you don't want the value of the `Word8`, but I've retrieved it with `peek` to demonstrate that the pointer is valid. You might be tempted to `return` the `Ptr` from inside [`withForeignPtr`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v:withForeignPtr), but the documentation warns against that:

> Note that it is not safe to return the pointer from the action and use it after the action completes. All uses of the pointer should be inside the `withForeignPtr` bracket. The reason for this unsafeness is the same as for [`unsafeForeignPtrToPtr`](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html#v%3AunsafeForeignPtrToPtr) below: the finalizer may run earlier than expected, because the compiler can only track usage of the `ForeignPtr` object, not a `Ptr` object made from it.

The code is straightforward:

```
doStuff :: ForeignPtr Word8 -> Int -> IO ()
doStuff fp i =
  withForeignPtr fp $ \p -> do
    let addr = p `plusPtr` i
    val <- peek addr :: IO Word8
    print (addr, val, chr $ fromIntegral val)
```

To approximate “a `Word8` in a File” from your question, the main program memory-maps a file and uses that buffer to do stuff with memory addresses.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  (p,offset,size) <- mmapFileForeignPtr path mode range
  forM_ [0 .. size-1] $ \i -> do
    doStuff p (offset + i)
  where
    path  = "/tmp/input.dat"
    mode  = ReadOnly
    range = Nothing
 -- range = Just (4,3)
```

Output:

```
(0x00007f1b40edd000,71,'G')
(0x00007f1b40edd001,117,'u')
(0x00007f1b40edd002,116,'t')
(0x00007f1b40edd003,101,'e')
(0x00007f1b40edd004,110,'n')
(0x00007f1b40edd005,32,' ')
(0x00007f1b40edd006,77,'M')
(0x00007f1b40edd007,111,'o')
(0x00007f1b40edd008,114,'r')
(0x00007f1b40edd009,103,'g')
(0x00007f1b40edd00a,101,'e')
(0x00007f1b40edd00b,110,'n')
(0x00007f1b40edd00c,33,'!')
(0x00007f1b40edd00d,10,'\n')
```

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for [ptrToIntPtr](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.2/docs/Foreign-Ptr.html#v:ptrToIntPtr) and probably [fromIntegral](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fromIntegral) to make it a CUInt.

Note that a CUInt cannot represent a pointer on all platforms, though.